# SQL Server 2008 R2 Mirroring for Deployment?

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am wondering if this is possible and to what degree of expertise I would need to accomplish it. I have 3 databases all built on the SQL Server 2k8R2 platform. 2 are on the same server and 1 is on another server linked to the same network. One is for development (you know the awesome one that you can break, bite, kick when no one is looking etc...) The other is a stage, and finally production. I am wondering if I could set-up some type of mirroring that would allow me to persist programmatic changes across all 3 of them. For example If I were to develop a new table, and SPROC on my dev database. Test and make sure all was well and working, is there a way when i commit my changes to have that table along with its key's, indexes, FK's, and the SPROC i created to be automatically generated in the other 2 databases without me having to re-script and run them. Forgive my ignorance, I know i can script the changes and just load up each one and run the script to generate all of the things I created, but I want to be able to do this in real time on the fly. Is this something that is a painless process which can be done easily? I do not care to replicate the data inside the table(s) only the programmatic bits of code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks much, 
John

Answer (score 3):

That is a very bad idea, and not the way you should handle deploying changes from Development to Staging and on to Production. By definition, you want no connection between development and production environments (they should ideally be using different security credentials to prevent accidental changes).

[**Also Note**: Database mirroring requires SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition]

Instead, use the Visual Studio 2008 GDE database project add-on (or now built-in with VS 2010). Alternatively, use [Redgate's synchronisation tools](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/). Both can incorporated into your automated build processes.

Visual Studio 2010: [Working with Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty.aspx)

- [Build and Deploy Databases to a Staging or Production Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193413.aspx)

One of the nice features of database projects is that in addition to being able to update a database inplace, they can also generate the scripted schema changes needed to update a target database without actually applying them.

Update: I currently use the VS2010 database projects in a workflow similiar to the following:

1. Get latest source code
2. Deploy current DB schema to my local SQL Server instance (includes pre-population of static reference data (and can load realistic system operational data as well)
3. Make any schema changes directly in the local database (and any associated code changes locally).
4. Build and test locally.
5. Use the database project schema comparison tool to compare the local DB with the model in the DB project, synchronise to generate pending scripted schema changes.
6. Check everything in.
7. one-click Deploy to system test  etc. (I've glassed over some of the details)

Comment: I'm not to concerned with the Production DB to be honest. I understand completely what you are saying though. I am more interested in keeping stage and production synced up. So if i build and test something on my local DB and it works i would like to be able to automatically put it in play on stage. I am thinking stage should always 100% mimic production with the idea that if it works on stage porting a change to prod should be simple. Am I looking at this completely the wrong way?

Comment: " I am thinking stage should always 100% mimic production with the idea that if it works on stage porting a change to prod should be simple" - that's correct. I use the VS2010 Database projects to do exactly that.

Comment: @user724525, I would strongly suggest looking at @Mitch Wheat's suggestion about using Red Gate tools as an alternative. Been using them for a similar workflow as above + source control since 2006, haven't had an issue. They back the schema up to, which is nice in case you make a mistake and would like to roll back. If RedGate's too pricey, look at [DevArt's] (http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/) offerings. Similar to RedGate's, but cheaper. Consider automating RedGate's tools to make the above workflow unattender (= less human errors).

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be considering more conventional development, build and deployment tools like Visual Studio Database Edition, the Red Gate tools, DBGhost, Team City, etc. These are the tools designed for the job.

Mirroring isn't likely to be a viable option for a whole host of reasons. Mirroring stage to production doesn't make much sense to me because the point of those enviornments is precisely that you can deploy them independently and that they aren't dependent on each other. You didn't even mention a test environment (maybe testing is what you use stage for?). In a test environment you usually also need the ability to redeploy, rollback and patch changes and data. I suspect mirroring would hinder rather than help testing.